# PostgreSQL delete row if condition met, else update some value

Tags: postgresql, clojure

I'm trying to delete a row based on a simple condition, if conditions are met, delete the row else update the row. Basically I'm tagging my data with `is_deleted`, so perform delete if `is_deleted` equals to true, if not, set the `is_deleted` value to true.

Right now what I'm doing is a simple query, check the `is_deleted` from the queried data and do something based on it.

A very simple pseudo code written in clojure ($n is just a placeholder for positional arguments):

```clj
(defn find-by-username 
  [db username]
  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1") ;; to illustrate the query

(defn delete-by-username-impl
  [db username]
  "DELETE FROM users WHERE username = $1")

(defn set-is-deleted
  [db username]
  "UPDATE users SET is_deleted = true WHERE username = $1")

(defn delete-by-username 
  [db username]
  (let [user (find-by-username db username)]
    (if (:is-deleted user)
      (delete-by-username-impl db username)
      (set-is-deleted db username))))
```

What I'm looking for is to hit the DB only once.

Comment: You could always wrap the logic in a procedure where :is-deleted would be an input to the procedure, this would also reduce the number of functions you'd need to interact with the db in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with hitting the database only once? Running one query? Then you can combine all the queries into one:

```sql
IF (SELECT is_deleted FROM users WHERE username = $1) THEN
  DELETE FROM users WHERE username = $1
ELSE
  UPDATE users SET is_deleted = true WHERE username = $1
END IF;
```

If you mean running all queries together or none of them in an isolated context (so that other clients cannot change the state like the `is_deleted` flag while the queries run), you can wrap the separate queries into a transaction using a [database transaction](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/06_databases/6-03_manipulating-an-SQL-database.asciidoc#transactions):

> Database transactions are available to ensure that multiple operations are performed atomically (i.e., all or none). The clojure.java.jdbc/with-db-transaction macro creates a transaction-aware connection from the database specification. Use the transaction-aware connection for the duration of the transaction:

```clj
;; Insert two new fruits atomically
(jdbc/with-db-transaction [trans-conn db-spec]
  (jdbc/insert! trans-conn :fruit {:name "Fig" :cost 12})
  (jdbc/insert! trans-conn :fruit {:name "Date" :cost 14}))
;; -> ({:grade nil, :unit nil, :cost 14, :appearance nil, :name "Date"})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious options

A. Call a function to do the delete for you. That can:

1. lock the row (`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`)
2. read the current flag setting
3. delete the row if the flag is set
4. set the flag if it isn't

B. Write a ["BEFORE DELETE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER)" trigger.

This can check the status of the flag and if it is unset, set it instead of deleting (return NULL). If the flag is already set, let the delete operation continue.

Triggers can sometimes be a bit "magical" for my tastes. If you don't know they are there then it can be confusing. In this case though, I think a trigger is probably a good choice.

Answer (score -1):

See “Merge Action with Quals” in https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/MergeTestExamples

Comment: Always read the pages you are linking to "This was never integrated into PostgreSQL, and requires significant work to be production quality "

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, unfortunately this feature never gets implemented.

Comment: @RichardHuxton Any opinions about this? Is it even doable?

Comment: Supposed to be in 11.  But can’t find it now.  Probably reverted. Quick solution is to write your own stored procedure.